# Ubuntu won't update from 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 12.10, updates, 13.04, update-manager

To update I typed in `sudo update-manager -d` into terminal and I got this code back (I had to edit the links):

```
W:GPG error: h.ttp://linux.dropbox.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FC918B335044912E,  
W:GPG error: h.ttp://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192, 
W:GPG error: h.ttp://ppa.launchpad.net jaunty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F104610CF0876AC9, 
W:GPG error: h.ttp://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B187F352479B857B,  
W:GPG error: h.ttp://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 86D36DFDE6A250EA,  
W:GPG error: h.ttp://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0,  
W:GPG error: h.ttp://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886,  
W:GPG error: h.ttp://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886,  
W:Failed to fetch h.ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found,  
W:Failed to fetch h.ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found,  
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources/list` with:

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
```

And see if that works.